# Splitting a string using regular expression -javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I have the following two strings

```
Ethanethiol, 2,2'-thiobis- Not available. 1 - 5
ethyl acetate 109159-22-0 1 - 5
```

In those above strings first one is the chemical name , next to it is its id no and last one is its percent in that product.So I want to split these strings in the below  manner so that it will be helpful for me for the page where there are different fields for diff section.

I want to split these strings like this

```
Ethanethiol, 2,2'-thiobis- 
Not available.   
1 
5
ethyl acetate
109159-22-0
1
5
```

I do not want to take any string variable.The code should be dynamic.I mean just input the string in those above format it will show the output as below.Here is my code for the second one

```
(function(){
 x=prompt("Enter Data");
re=/([\D\d]*)([\d-]+)\s*(\d*\s*\.?\s*\d*)\s*-\s*(\d*\s*\.?\s*\d*)/;
alert("[0]"+x.match(re)[0]);alert("[1]"+x.match(re)[1]);alert("[2]"+x.match(re)[2]);
alert("[3]"+x.match(re)[3]);alert("[4]"+x.match(re)[4]);})();
```

But as in first one there is nos so it is not working for the code.Any Suggestions please?

Comment: Rules for splitting are needed in question. Why `ethyl acetate` is one token?

Answer (score 0):

use this pattern

```
\s\s+|\s-\s
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/72)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion ,but if there is only single space ,then?

Comment: what is your criteria for splitting the sentence?

Comment: Actually I have a page which has different text fields for different strings.I mean in those above string ethyl acetate is the chemical name , next to it is its id no and last one is its percent in that product.So I want to split these strings in the above manner.